# Custom Taxonomies not appearing in Admin

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I've made a plugin of a custom content type and taxonomy. The CPT is showing fine, but the Taxonomies are not. There's a lot of code, but the taxonomy information is parsed below:

Full code can be found here on [github](https://github.com/ksascomm/ksas-musems-exhibits/blob/master/ksasexhibitons.php)

```
    <?php

function check_exhibition_type_tax() {
        $labels = array(
            'name'                  => _x( 'Exhibition Types', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name'         => _x( 'Exhibition Type', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'add_new'               => _x( 'Add New Exhibition Type', 'Exhibition Type'),
            'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Exhibition Type' ),
            'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Exhibition Type' ),
            'new_item'              => __( 'New Exhibition Type' ),
            'view_item'             => __( 'View Exhibition Type' ),
            'search_items'          => __( 'Search Exhibition Types' ),
            'not_found'             => __( 'No Exhibition Type found' ),
            'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No Exhibition Type found in Trash' ),
        );

        $pages = array('ksasexhibits');

        $args = array(
            'labels'            => $labels,
            'singular_label'    => __('Exhibiton Type'),
            'public'            => true,
            'show_ui'           => true,
            'hierarchical'      => true,
            'show_tagcloud'     => false,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
            'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'exhibiton', 'with_front' => false ),
         );
        register_taxonomy('exhibition_type', $pages, $args);
}

    add_action('init', 'register_exhibition_type_tax');

function check_exhibition_type_terms(){

    //see if we already have populated any terms
    $term = get_terms ('exhibition_type', array( 'hide_empty' => false ) );

    //if no terms then lets add our terms
      if( empty( $term ) ){
        $terms = define_exhibition_type_terms();
        foreach( $terms as $term ){
            if( !term_exists( $term['name'], 'exhibition_type' ) ){
                wp_insert_term( $term['name'], 'exhibition_type', array( 'slug' => $term['slug'] ) );
            }
        }
    }

}

add_action ( 'init', 'check_exhibition_type_terms' );

function define_exhibiton_type_terms(){

$terms = array(
        '0' => array( 'name' => 'Campus Partnerships','slug' => 'campus'),
        '1' => array( 'name' => 'Community Partnerships','slug' => 'community'),
        '2' => array( 'name' => 'Independent Study','slug' => 'independent'),
        '3' => array( 'name' => 'Digital Work.','slug' => 'digital'),
        '4' => array( 'name' => 'Mellon Foundation','slug' => 'mellon'),
    );

    return $terms;
}

add_filter( 'manage_edit-ksasexhibits_columns', 'my_ksasexhibits_columns' ) ;

function my_ksasexhibits_columns( $columns ) {

    $columns = array(
        'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
        'title' => __( 'Name' ),
        'exhibitons' => __( 'Exhibiton Type' ),
        'date' => __( 'Date' ),
    );

    return $columns;
}

add_action( 'manage_studyfields_posts_custom_column', 'my_manage_ksasexhibits_columns', 10, 2 );

function my_manage_program_columns( $column, $post_id ) {
    global $post;

    switch( $column ) {

        /* If displaying the 'program_type' column. */

        case 'exhibitons' :

            /* Get the program_types for the post. */
            $terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'exhibition_type' );

            /* If terms were found. */
            if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {

                $out = array();

                /* Loop through each term, linking to the 'edit posts' page for the specific term. */
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    $out[] = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
                        esc_url( add_query_arg( array( 'post_type' => $post->post_type, 'exhibiton_type' => $term->slug ), 'edit.php' ) ),
                        esc_html( sanitize_term_field( 'name', $term->name, $term->term_id, 'exhibiton_type', 'display' ) )
                    );
                }

                /* Join the terms, separating them with a comma. */
                echo join( ', ', $out );
            }

            /* If no terms were found, output a default message. */
            else {
                _e( 'No Exhibitons Assigned' );
            }

            break;
        /* Just break out of the switch statement for everything else. */
        default :
            break;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seemed to be an issue with the way you registered the taxonomy. 
I prefer to register the taxonomy first, before registering the post type.
[image: Exhibit Types]

I submitted a pull request but here ya go:

```
<?php

// hook into the init action and call create_book_taxonomies when it fires
add_action( 'init', 'create_ksasexhibits_taxonomies', 0 );

// create two taxonomies, genres and writers for the post type "book"
function create_ksasexhibits_taxonomies() {
    // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
    $labels = array(
            'name'                  => _x( 'Exhibition Types', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name'         => _x( 'Exhibition Type', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'add_new'               => _x( 'Add New Exhibition Type', 'Exhibition Type'),
            'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Exhibition Type' ),
            'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Exhibition Type' ),
            'new_item'              => __( 'New Exhibition Type' ),
            'view_item'             => __( 'View Exhibition Type' ),
            'search_items'          => __( 'Search Exhibition Types' ),
            'not_found'             => __( 'No Exhibition Type found' ),
            'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No Exhibition Type found in Trash' ),
        );

        $args = array(
            'labels'            => $labels,
            'singular_label'    => __('Exhibiton Type'),
            'public'            => true,
            'show_ui'           => true,
            'hierarchical'      => true,
            'show_tagcloud'     => false,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
            'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'exhibiton', 'with_front' => false ),
         );
    register_taxonomy( 'exhibition_type', 'ksasexhibits', $args );
}

function register_ksasexhibits_posttype() {
    $labels = array(
            'name'              => _x( 'Exhibits & Programs', 'post type general name' ),
            'singular_name'     => _x( 'Exhibit', 'post type singular name' ),
            'add_new'           => __( 'Add New Exhibit & Program' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Exhibit & Program' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Exhibit & Program' ),
            'new_item'          => __( 'New Exhibit & Program' ),
            'view_item'         => __( 'View Exhibit & Program' ),
            'search_items'      => __( 'Search Exhibit & Program' ),
            'not_found'         => __( 'No Exhibit & Program found' ),
            'not_found_in_trash'=> __( 'No Exhibit & Program found in Trash' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( '' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'Exhibits & Programs' )
        );

        //$taxonomies = array( 'exhibition_type' );

        $supports = array('title','revisions','thumbnail' );

        $post_type_args = array(
            'labels'            => $labels,
            'singular_label'    => __('Exhibit & Program'),
            'public'            => true,
            'show_ui'           => true,
            'publicly_queryable'=> true,
            'query_var'         => true,
            'capability_type'   => 'post',
            'has_archive'       => false,
            'hierarchical'      => true,
            'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'exhibitons', 'with_front' => false ),
            'supports'          => $supports,
            'menu_position'     => 5,
            //'taxonomies'      => $taxonomies,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true
         );
    register_post_type('ksasexhibits',$post_type_args);
}
add_action('init', 'register_ksasexhibits_posttype');

function define_exhibiton_type_terms() {
    $terms = array(
        '0' => array( 'name' => 'Campus Partnerships','slug' => 'campus'),
        '1' => array( 'name' => 'Community Partnerships','slug' => 'community'),
        '2' => array( 'name' => 'Independent Study','slug' => 'independent'),
        '3' => array( 'name' => 'Digital Work.','slug' => 'digital'),
        '4' => array( 'name' => 'Mellon Foundation','slug' => 'mellon'),
        );
    return $terms;
}

function check_exhibition_type_terms(){

    //see if we already have populated any terms
    $terms = get_terms ('exhibition_type', array( 'hide_empty' => false ) );

    //if no terms then lets add our terms
    if( empty( $terms ) ){
    $terms = array(
        '0' => array( 'name' => 'Campus Partnerships','slug' => 'campus'),
        '1' => array( 'name' => 'Community Partnerships','slug' => 'community'),
        '2' => array( 'name' => 'Independent Study','slug' => 'independent'),
        '3' => array( 'name' => 'Digital Work.','slug' => 'digital'),
        '4' => array( 'name' => 'Mellon Foundation','slug' => 'mellon'),
        );
        foreach( $terms as $term ){
            if( !term_exists( $term['name'], 'exhibition_type' ) ){
                wp_insert_term( $term['name'], 'exhibition_type', array( 'slug' => $term['slug'] ) );
            }
        }
    }

}

add_action ( 'init', 'check_exhibition_type_terms' );

?>
```